# Convert excel file to HTML table in Symfony2

Tags: html, phpexcel, display

I just want to display a Excel file in a twig view with a Symfony2.5 Controller.

With PHPExcel, I can do this trick and it works :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$filename = 'filename.xlsx';
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
$excel = $reader->load($filename);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "HTML");
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
<?php

echo $writer->generateStyles(true);

?>
</style>

<body>
<?php

echo $writer->generateSheetData();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do the same thing in my Controller in Symfony 2.5 ?

Actually i have this :

```
public function newAction()
{
    $filename = 'filename.xls';
    $reader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
    $excel = $reader->load($filename);
    $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "HTML");

    echo $writer->generateStyles();
    echo $writer->generateSheetData();
}
```

What should i have in my render view ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: You should include your code in the question instead of linking to an image of it. That way it's never lost in the event the image host goes down or the image itself is removed.

Comment: thanks, it's done.you can test it now.